# tokenizing bash script commands

Tags: bash, tokenize, word2vec

I am planning to create Word2vec embeddings for command lines. To create Word2vec I need to tokenize the command line. Any suggestions of what could be the best way to tokenize command lines?

Lot of existing tokenizers use space or any delimiter we mention like (, .). But wanted to check any better tokenizer as these delimiters doesn't work for a sample case like

`/bin/bash -l -c docker rmi $(docker images | awk '{print $3}'); true`

Comment: Word2Vec is intended for natural language processing. Do you really think it's appropriate for processing a programming language?

Comment: Could you explain this for someone not familiar with `word2vec`? It's not clear that POSIX-compliant shell parsing *can* be transformed in a way that works for you, without understanding the use case more clearly. (The number of shell words that the output of `$(docker images | awk '{print $3}')` is parsed into is completely undefined; it could be no words at all, if `docker images` has no output; it could be a word per file in the current directory, if the output is `*`).

Comment: ...if you want to read the grammar specification, it lives at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02

Comment: ...whereas if you want to find a quality high-level parser for shell that's already written, you might want to start with https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck, which parses to a proper AST.

Comment: (...that said, it's notable that `bash -c docker anything` throws away all the arguments after `docker`, assigning them to arguments that are never read, so the example given isn't exactly a useful statement; if you're parsing output of `ps` -- or software like `docker` that does a sloppy-to-the-point-of-malpractice job of logging command lines it generates -- you're probably seeing a misrepresentation of the *actual* command line, which was presumably more like `bash -l -c 'docker rmi ...'`).

Comment: I am sure I do not understand what you are trying to achieve but to tokenise a command line, you probably need a parser (containing a lexical analyzer and syntax analyser) such as the ones incorporated into antler, yacc, javacc or similar. [Parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will check if I can use lexical analyzer and parser to get the tokens from the commands